# Centered text and left aligned button in panel heading using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to center some text in the heading of a panel, along with a left-aligned button on the same row. The approach I'm currently taking works sort of OK for small widths, but as soon as the window gets to .col-sm territory (>750px) the text is no longer centered and instead seems to align right. Plus I'm not actually sure if this approach of trying to overlap a col-xs-1 and col-md-12 is really centering the text even for small window widths.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="container" style="padding:0;">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-1">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Button</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center">Heading</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r9zo180f/8/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**stdout**, Hi there. You can actually have the **Heading** in the center if you like.
I mean actually centered in the full width. Your example is offset by 1 col.
I do it without that extra col offset and the button still to the left.

Have a look at this example in my **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/xLd3qf9z/embedded/result/)** to see how the Header  text is actually centered in the whole div.
It has a lot let cols/row etc.

I left one of the other examples above so you can see the difference.

Here is the CSS used for this example.

```
<style>
.align-left{
   float:left !important; 
}
.center-text-vert{
   line-height:30px;  /*height of the button*/
}
.center {
   text-align: center; 
   margin-right: 55px; /*width from the left to the far right of the button */   
}  
</style>
```

[image]

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 ">
      <div class="panel panel-primary ">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="center-text-vert">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm align-left">Button</button>
                <div class="center">  
                    Heading
                </div>   
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks. Even takes care of vertical centering which was my next task. :) BTW the reason for the "col-sm-3" and "col-sm-8" columns is that I have other content in the "col-sm-3" which I figured I'd remove for clarity. But of course there is no way anyone could have been able to determine that intent from my question. For folks looking at this answer you'll need to take a look at the Fiddle to see the associated CSS. Or, AngularJR, you may want to add the CSS to the code in your response.

Comment: HI there, Great that this is working for you. Yes, I thought the text alignment would look better. For this I used `line-height:30px;` . Yes I can also add the css.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the container inside you panel and use pull-left class for your button and text-center class for your heading and see if that works for you.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-1">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left">Button</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-11 text-center">Heading</div>
                        </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: While it's true that you shouldn't nest container classes (Bootstrap documentation is pretty explicit about that), this doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

What I guess you want is for the title to be full width at `xs` size and only take up a portion of the screen at `sm` and higher. To do that, remove the empty column and instead apply an offset. Also, note there are 12 columns so offsetting by 3 (i.e. 3 columns on the left and 3 on the right) means the middle column can only be 6 wide. I've set this one to be offset by 2 as an example. I've also fixed the inner columns to add up to 12 (although you should not nest `container` classes:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Button</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-11" style="text-align:center">Heading</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```